# How do you plot locations on a google maps SDK with coordinates from parse on Xcode 5 for iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, parse-platform

I am currently designing an app which i need to plot locations from various coordinates I have collected and stored on parse. Its currently stored as a string, I think I may need to save the object as a Geopoint? Never the less, I am wondering how I would actually plot that data to show up on the google maps SDK? - I've been looking for tutorials and can't find anything, I am new to coding so its difficult, but very willing to learn. I just need to know what code I would write in this situation to make that happen. Any help would be great! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer

---

One way to do this would be:

Get a handle to the GoogleMap object that you want to place the location markers.

Extract the (lat,lng) coordinates from string to doubles.

Then use the lat,lng and place a marker on the map like so:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"Hello World";
marker.map = googleMap ; // this is the handle to your google map object
```

Hope this brief answer sets you in right direction.